# Writing text information to existing CSV file with Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I am appending an array of numbers to an existing excel file using this:

```
dlmwrite(mydatafile,newdataarray,'-append');
```

I need to add a column to the beginning of the new row for a text identifier (employee name), but I can't get Matlab to write the name to a single cell. Does anyone have any ideas how I'd be able to do this?

Comment: is the column you are adding available for write in excel? if so, are you using quotes properly? Are you saying that your string is being written character by character in different cells?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear, for example it is not completely defined how you can add a column to a row.

If the following does not work I would recommend you to provide a small scale example of the data that you have and the things you want to append.

Assuming you just need to get this done and are not looking for a pretty solution you could try to:

First read it into matlab

Then perform the operation that you like

Then write it to a new file

This will allow you to do pretty much anything but whether it is convenient depends on your specific needs.

Comment: @AK4749 that's my issue exactly. The string that I want to write into a single cell is being written character by character into seperate cells. Also the characters overwrite the data that was already in the file (instead of appending to the next available empty cell).